# How to get more IExtensions from org.eclipse.ui.ide.projectNatureImages?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

im getting java natures using this:

```
IExtensionPoint ex= Platform.getExtensionRegistry().getExtensionPoint("org.eclipse.core.resources.natures");
```

and getting nature images using this:

```
 IExtensionPoint ex2= Platform.getExtensionRegistry().getExtensionPoint("org.eclipse.ui.ide.projectNatureImages");
```

so, i have an object that contains an IExtension element and an Image element:

```
public class NatureInformationWrapper {

    private IExtension extension;
    private Image image;

    public IExtension getExtension() {
        return extension;
    }
    public void setExtension(IExtension extension) {
        this.extension = extension;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public void setImage(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

i set the IExtensions doing it:

```
ArrayList<String> identifiers=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<NatureInformationWrapper> extensionsList= new 
ArrayList<NatureInformationWrapper>();

for(int index=0; index< extensions.length; index++) {
    extensionsList.add(niw);
}
```

and i set the image doing this:

```
    for(int index2=0; index2<imageExtensionsList.size(); index2++) {
            IConfigurationElement[] configurationElements=imageExtensionsList.get(index2).getConfigurationElements();
            for(int index3=0; index3<configurationElements.length; index3++) {              
                String natureId=imageExtensionsList.get(index2).getConfigurationElements()[index3].getAttribute("natureId");
                for(int listInputIndex=0; listInputIndex<extensionsList.size(); listInputIndex++) {
                    String currentNatureId=extensionsList.get(listInputIndex).getExtension().getUniqueIdentifier();
                    if(natureId.equals(currentNatureId)) {
                        Image img=null;

                        String icon = configurationElements[index3].getAttribute("icon");
                        icon = icon.replace("$nl$", "");
                        if (icon !=null) {
                            final String   cont  = configurationElements[index3].getContributor().getName();
                            final Bundle   bundle= Platform.getBundle(cont);
                            final URL      entry = bundle.getEntry(icon);
                            final ImageDescriptor des = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(entry);
                            img= des.createImage();
                        }
                     extensionsList.get(listInputIndex).setImage(img);
                    }
                }

            }


    }
```

But `ex2.getExtensions();` is always returning one element, and it is the IExtension for org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature.

My question is, how can i get more IExtensions  from `ex2.getExtensions();`?

do i need to install something?

Comment: Since `ex2` refers to `org.eclipse.ui.ide.projectNatureImages` I'd assume you can only ever get one element. I'm not expert in those depths of Eclipse but I'd guess nature images would be used to display the nature icons on top of the project icons and there's not much space to display more than one.

Comment: `org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature` is the only project nature image declared in the core Eclipse. Eclipse WST adds a few more but if you don't have that installed it is correct that you only get one entry.

Comment: @greg-449 thank you so much, i installed  WST tools, and now i can see more icons .